# C# - How to extract the file name and extension from a path?

Tags: c#, file, path

So, say I have

```
string path = "C:\\Program Files\\Program\\File.exe";
```

How do I get only "File.exe"? I was thinking something with split (see below), but what I tried doesn't work...

This is my code.

```
        List<string> procs = new List<string>(); //Used to check if designated process is already running
        foreach (Process prcs in Process.GetProcesses())
            procs.Add(prcs.ProcessName); //Add each process to the list
        foreach (string l in File.ReadAllLines("MultiStart.txt")) //Get list of processes (full path)
            if (!l.StartsWith("//")) //Check if it's commented out
                if (!procs.Contains(l.Split('\\')[l.Split('\\').Length - 1])) //Check if process is already running
                    Process.Start(l);
```

I'm probably just being a noob. ._.

Answer (score 127):

`System.IO` has different classes to work with files and directories. Between them, one of the most useful one is `Path` which has lots of static helper methods for working with files and folders:

```cs
Path.GetExtension(yourPath); // returns .exe
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(yourPath); // returns File
Path.GetFileName(yourPath); // returns File.exe
Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath); // returns C:\Program Files\Program
```

Comment: And `Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath)` will fetch the folder path.

Answer (score 21):

You're looking for `Path.GetFileName(string)`.

Comment: That's not what your question said, though.

Answer (score 10):

With the last character search you can get the right result.

```
string path = "C:\\Program Files\\Program\\fatih.gurdal.docx";
string fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(((char)92))+ 1);
int index = fileName.LastIndexOf('.');
string onyName= fileName.Substring(0, index);
string fileExtension = fileName.Substring(index + 1);
Console.WriteLine("Full File Name: "+fileName);
Console.WriteLine("Full File Ony Name: "+onyName);
Console.WriteLine("Full File Extension: "+fileExtension);
```

Output:

> Full File Name: fatih.gurdal.docx
>
> Full File Ony Name: fatih.gurdal
>
> Full File Extension: docx

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful in my scenario as file name is in a string but not a physical file.

Comment: NOTE for .NET Core - you should be searching for the last position of DirectorySeparatorChar and AltDirectorySeparatorChar.  +1 to the post because it predates widespread .net core usage and it is the only answer that 'shows the code'. If you want to hard code it use `(char)47` as this is the Unix separator character and Windows's AltDirectorySeparatorChar

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to remove any .sometext before the .extension

```
//Remove all extensions "any .sometext.extension" from the file name
var newFileName= Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
//Combine the the new file name with its actual extension "last .extension"
var fileNameWithExtension = newFileName+ "." + fileName.Split('.')[fileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
```