# How can I get file tile(name) from file full path in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I wanna get file title(only filename, and extension) How can I get this?

for example :  ftp://111.111.111.111:3333/file/file01.bmp

I just wanna get "file01.bmp" in VB6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to extract the file name and extension from a path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003555/c-sharp-how-to-extract-the-file-name-and-extension-from-a-path)

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the question is for VB6,  not VB.Net or C#.
Please include the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim filename As String

filename = fso.GetFileName("ftp://111.111.111.111:3333/file/file01.bmp")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Path.GetFileName`

```
var filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
```

in VB.Net

```
Dim filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath)
```

Comment: Down voters, please leave your comment. I'm really surprised someone down voting an accepted answer and not leaving any comments.