# How to read byte array from an incoming collection object of dictionay

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, c#-4.0, byte

I have a property like below:

```
public Dictionary<string, Byte[]> Collection{ get; set; }
```

Now I need to loop through and get only the byte into a byte array (This is basically images array. How do I do?

I tried something like below but I know its wrong, but something similar we try to read? It may have upto 10 items. It can have 1 or upto 10...

**Update** I prefer to read all the upto 10 or whatever is in the array upto 10 into "image" array below...a variable I have....

```
byte[] image = new byte[10];
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> val in input.Collection)
                {
                    image = // read all the bytes alone as array...It can have 1 or 2 or upto 10...

                }
```

**Update**

i have this

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"image.jpg",
      "doc":"0x255044462D312E370A25E4E3CFD20A342030206F626A0A3C3C2F537562747970652F496D6167652F5769647468203431332F486569676874203132332F4D61736B5B323535203235355D2F426974735065724",
      "numberId":"2adb2911-9dea-4ca3-9a48-a4ef918c9ee8",
      "RefID":"2adb2911-9dea-4ca3-9a48-a4ef918c9ee8"
   }
]
```

I want to read the "doc" into this list...so basically this data structure can have upto 10 item....each may have different file types like .jpg, .tiff etc, I want to at least extract the "extension type - corresponding byte value

Also, I need to have corresponding item name, the first value in the data above

Comment: So you want to get all the bytes, from each item in the dictionary and store them in what? do you want to add all the bytes together? or do you want a list of byte arrays?

Comment: Also you say you have a property called `Collection` then you are looping over something called `request.Attachment` can you please update your question and add **ALL** the appropriate information we need to answer it

Comment: @MichaelRandall: Thank you for your guidance, and pick, I agree and update my question.

Comment: @Learner, assuming that your `input.Collection` is already populated with the data from the provided json above, and that `val.Key` is the filename, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(val.Key)` to extract the extension and `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(val.Key)` to extract just the filename.

Comment: @yv989c: Thank you that helped me. One quick question, I have file name as "Image.jpg" how to I find the extension "jpg"

Comment: @yv989c: Got it, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003555/c-sharp-how-to-extract-the-file-name-and-extension-from-a-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is a little obscure to me, but it seems to me that you just want to read the byte array of each element in your dictionary.

If that's the case, you only need to interact with the `val.Value` property. If you want to assign its value to your `image` variable you just do this:

```
byte[] image;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> val in input.Collection)
{
    image = val.Value;
    // Then do something with 'image', like: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes($"C:\\MyImage_{val.Key}.jpg", image);
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats simple to nuderstand. One question, I want to assign the String in the structure below which is key. How to do ? Its like Image 1 - .JPG, Image 2 -.tiff etc

Comment: @Learner, sorry but I don't understand the question... can you please update your question above with the explanation? or create a new question?